# Exception when performing restart from replica set to standalone

Tags: mongodb, exception, database-replication

I am currently experimenting with MongoDB replica set mechanism.
I already have a working standalone Mongo server with a main database of about 20GB of data.

I decided to convert this mongo server to a primary replica set server, then added a 2nd machine with a similar configuration (but a newer mongo version), as a secondary replica set server.
This works fine, all data is replicated to the secondary as expected.

But I would like to perform some alteration operations on the data (because somehow, my data model has changed and I need to, for example rename some properties, or convert references to a simple ObjectId, some things like that). By the same time I would like to update the first server which has an old version (2.4) to the last version available (2.6).

So I decided to follow the instructions on the MongoDB website to [perform maintenance on replica set members](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members/).

1. shut down the secondary server. (ok)
2. restart server as standalone on another port (both servers usually run on 27017)

   mongod --dbpath /my/database/path --port 37017

And then, the server never restarts correctly and I get this:

```
2014-10-03T08:20:58.716+0200 [initandlisten] opening db:  myawesomedb
2014-10-03T08:20:58.735+0200 [initandlisten] myawesomedb Assertion failure _name == nsToDatabaseSubstring( ns ) src/mongo/db/catalog/database.cpp 472
2014-10-03T08:20:58.740+0200 [initandlisten] myawesomedb 0x11e6111 0x1187e49 0x116c15e 0x8c2208 0x765f0e 0x76ab3f 0x76c62f 0x76cedb 0x76d475 0x76d699 0x7fd958c3eec5 0x764329 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x11e6111]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x159) [0x1187e49]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x17e) [0x116c15e]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8Database13getCollectionERKNS_10StringDataE+0x288) [0x8c2208]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo17checkForIdIndexesEPNS_8DatabaseE+0x19e) [0x765f0e]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x76ab3f]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi+0x5df) [0x76c62f]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x1b) [0x76cedb]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x76d475]
 /usr/bin/mongod(main+0x9) [0x76d699]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fd958c3eec5]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x764329]
2014-10-03T08:20:58.756+0200 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 0 assertion src/mongo/db/catalog/database.cpp:472, terminating
2014-10-03T08:20:58.757+0200 [initandlisten] dbexit:
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Note that at this time, the first server is still running as primary member.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are hitting a [bug](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/9/23/509) in VMWare here (<s>can you confirm you are using VMWare VMs?</s> **confirmed**) - I have seen it confirmed on [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1371591) and Fedora so far.  The bug causes pieces of previous data to not be zero'ed out when creating the MongoDB namespace files (not always, but sometimes).  That previous data essentially manifests as corruption in the namespace files and leads to the assertion you saw.

To work around the issue, there will be a fix released in MongoDB versions 2.4.12 and 2.6.5+ as part of [SERVER-15369](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15369).  The OS/Kernel level fix will eventually percolate down from the kernel bug and the Ubuntu patch, but that may take some time to actually be available as an official update (hence the need for the workaround change in MongoDB itself in the interim).

The issue will only become apparent when you upgrade to 2.6 because of additional checking added to that version that was not present in 2.4, however the corruption is still present, just not reported on version 2.4

If you still have your primary running, and it does not have the corruption, I would recommend syncing a secondary that is not on a VMWare VM and/or taking a backup of your files as soon as possible for safety - there is no automatic way to fix this corruption right now.

You can also look at using version 2.6.5 once it is released ([2.6.5 rc4](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-announce/QY-gOQKvq4I) is available as of writing this which includes the fix).  You will still need to resync with that version off your good source to create a working secondary, but at least there will then be no corruption of the ns files.

**Updates:**

- Version 2.6.5 which includes the fix mentioned was [released on October 9th](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-announce/3mTe_rdcAxw)
- Version 2.4.12 which includes the fix was [released on October 16th](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-announce/0s9xjU0xuWc)
- Official MongoDB Advisory: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-announce/gPjazaAePoo

Comment: Oh god, this seems to be exactly the problem. And yes I use VMWare VMs, I even tried to remove manually the local.* files before restarting as standalone the secondary, and then I saw weird things in the log file (with the IndexRebuilder), like detecting an ObjectId as a collection name, or just a few characters, parts of words or something like that.
I will try your solution, it won't be easy, because everything in my company runs on ESX servers which I don't have my hands on.
For now, I think I'll try to update mongo to 2.6 to be sure.

Comment: There is the possibility that if you provision your disks as SATA instead of SCSI (the default) this can be avoided because it would then use a different driver - not sure if you have that option, or what the potential performance implications would be (if any) though

Comment: Ok, I will try this first.
I just saw that even the 2.6.x version is not marked as "stable", what I believed. My experiments here are obviously done on local test servers, but our production servers will likely have this problem...Hope that the "SATA solution" will work. Thanks anyway, I didn't find anything for days about this.

Comment: In addition to Adam's suggested workaround, we believe this issue only affects volumes using LVM, so you if SATA is not satisfactory, configuring the volume not to use LVM might do the trick.